# Converting String of letters to Int Array.

Tags: arrays, string, int

I have been struggling for some time now trying to convert a string parameter of letters into an int array inside of a method other than the main method. The int of arrays would then be returned. For instance:

I want the alphabet to be converted into an int array with corresponding numbers to their letters. For example:

Input string: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
Output array: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 .....]

My idea is to build an int array of index 25 and fill it with a for loop, but I am not sure how to proceed from there or if that is even the right way to approach this.

any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In C# you would do something like this:

```
 public int[] ConvertStringToIntArray(string letters)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        foreach (var letter in letters.ToCharArray())
        {
            numbers.Add((letter - 'A'));
        }

        return numbers.ToArray();
    }
```

If you want it to handle upper and lower case letters the same, 'a' == 0 and 'A' == 0, just change the foreach line to say `letters.ToUpper().ToCharArray()` as shown below:

```
 public int[] ConvertStringToIntArray(string letters)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        foreach (var letter in letters.ToUpper().ToCharArray())
        {
            numbers.Add((letter - 'A'));
        }

        return numbers.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through each character in the array and pass it to a method to get the integer value.  A method similar to the below method should work on returning the int value you are looking for on both lower and upper case alphanumeric characters:

```
public int GetIntValue(char alphanumericChar)
{
    return (int)alphanumericChar % 32 - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know is that characters already have a corresponding decimal value. All you have to do is convert them. For example, in C#:

```
        char s = 'a';            
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        Console.Write(i);
        //Output: 97
```

Here is a helpful reference: http://www.asciitable.com/